# Routing App Coverage File keeps loading after submitting to Apple

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, geojson

I'm new to Apple and have developed an App. After submitting the App to Apple, I got the following errors after submitting my build to Apple.

1. ITMS-90117: Missing routing app coverage file: You must upload a routing app coverage file in App Store Connect if you register as a routing app.
2. The status of your app has changed to Invalid Binary.

After researching the routing coverage file, I found how to create one and submit it in Apple Connect. I submitted the file with the .geojson for the whole world as shown below:

```
{
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                [
                    -360.0000,
                    -90.0000
                ],
                [
                    -360.0000,
                    90.0000
                ],
                [
                    -000.0000,
                    90.0000
                ],
                [
                    -000.0000,
                    -90.0000
                ],
                [
                    -360.0000,
                    -90.0000
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

But, after choosing the Routing App Coverage file for submission, the section keeps loading and not even giving me an error of some sort even a notification, nothing. I wanted to know if I am doing anything wrong and if there is something wrong I am doing, I am kindly asking for help with the .geojson file coordinates that cover the whole world and the file submission in Apple Connect.

Below is a screenshot of what's happening in Apple Connect after submitting the file.

[image: Apple Connect Screenshot]

It has been more than 3 hours whilst it's like that. Kindly asking for help, it's now frustrating.

Comment: Is your app a navigation app?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, yes it has a section that does navigation

Comment: And your app can provide navigation directions for anywhere on earth - Note this means that your app determines the route and provides turn by turn directions.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, that's it

Comment: @Paulw11, refreshed Apple Connect again and tried to upload my file, and it worked after a couple of hours.